# Strange server connection issue between two networks

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2003, latency

I have two sites connected with 2 encryption devices on either side.
Each site has a single flat switch connected to the encrption device on each side.
Site A has servers.
Site B has workstations.
Systems are directly plugged into the switch at their site.

Site A has a class C network.
Site B has a different class C network.

Site A has several servers.
Server 1 works fine.
Server 2 has the issue.
Server 2 is Windows 2003 x64

If I connect from workstation 1 to server 1 via remote desktop or file share, everything is nice and fast.

If I connect from server 1 to server 2 via remote desktop or file share, everthing is nice and fast.

If I connect from workstation 1 to server 2 via remote desktop or file share, everything is very slow and often times out. This goes the same for any workstation at site B.

If I ping from workstation 1 to server 2, everything goes through fine.
To troubleshoot I have:
Changed the IP on the adapter.
Removed the adapter and reinstalled the driver.
Checked all settings on the adapter to match settings on an identical adapter on a server without the issue.
Checked the logs on the switch to check for any errors that would indicate a hardware issue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I woudl suggest that you check your path MTU and adjust your NIC accordingly. I've seen this happen when routers would drop oversized packets without sending back the proper ICMP messages (or when these messages would be dropped by a firewall on the path and not acted upon).

Comment: I figured it out before I checked your comment but you are correct. Strange thing is the MTU was not set on any server on any adapter, but for whatever reason, this one was having problems. I set it to 1300 and life is good.